# Inserting python variable in SPARQL

Tags: python, variables, sparql

I have a string variable I want to pass in my SPARQL query and I can't get it to work.

```
title = 'Good Will Hunting'

[str(s) for s, in graph.query('''
    PREFIX ddis: <http://ddis.ch/atai/> 
    PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
    PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
    PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/> 
    
    SELECT ?lbl WHERE {
        ?movie rdfs:label  $title@en .
        ?movie wdt:P57 ?director .
        ?director rdfs:label ?lbl .
    }
    ''')]
```

It doesn't work and I get an error. The query is correct as it works if I manualy enter the name when I replace `$title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String interpolation in python can be achieved with the `%s` symbol (for string variables):

```
title = 'Good Will Hunting'

[str(s) for s, in graph.query('''
    PREFIX ddis: <http://ddis.ch/atai/> 
    PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
    PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
    PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/> 
    
    SELECT ?lbl WHERE {
        ?movie rdfs:label "%s"@en .
        ?movie wdt:P57 ?director .
        ?director rdfs:label ?lbl .
    }
    ''' % title)]
```

Note that I also added quotes (`"%s"`), that are necessary for specifying a string in SPARQL.